# Updating a dictionary entry value by reference in python

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I can create reference to a dictionary's value as the following:

```py
vehicle_type = 'car'
vehicle_types = {vehicle_type : 0}
vehicle_count = vehicle_types.get(vehicle_type)
```

Is it possible to increment  `vehicle_count` in such a way that `vehicle_types[vehicle_type]` is also incremented (visa versa)?

Comment: What are you trying to increment? `vehicle_count` is zero?

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can index the dict by doing `vehicle_count = vehicle_types[vehicle_type]` as well

Comment: Please read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html Python doesn't have different ways to "access things by reference or by value". Python's assignment/reference semantics are quite simple and straightforward, and you should try to understand them on their own terms, and not borrow terminology / mental-models from very different languages like C++

Comment: Python's `int` object does not support incrementing, so what you are asking is nonsensical. It may sound like I'm being coy or purposely obtuse, but once you really understand a few basic things about [Python's Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) and how this interacts with immutability this will become very clear and a big thing about Python will just make sense.

Comment: @coldspeed so I can count the number of different vehicles in my program. The code above is simplified version of my code, I have many calls to `vehicle_types[vehicle_type]` in my actually code and I would like abstract it to a variable. 

That is correct vehicle_count is zero (in this example).

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, you should *probably just explain that exactly*. This is a classic X-Y problem. It sounds like you just want to count things, something very simple and straightforward, without digging into the weeds of Python's semantics (although, again, read that link and this should all become very clear, and you should want to udnerstand it anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about "pointers" within Python (which isn't really a thing exactly, but you can pass data structures which might be good enough?). Perhaps if you implement a list you can achieve the desired effect like such:

```
vehicle_types = {'car': [0]}
vehicle_count = vehicle_types['car']

vehicle_types['car'][0] += 2 # We only change one of the values

print(vehicle_types['car'], vehicle_count) # both values are changed though
```

Outputs:

> [2] [2]

In this case we have changed both values by assigning one to "point" to the list contained at `vehicle_types['car']` and then only changing the value within the dictionary.

Comment: I have to tried to word my question better, please let me know if you do not understand.

Comment: @JoshMartin I've edited my post to be a possible solution to your problem

Comment: Is it possible to increase the value of `vehicle_types['car'][0]` by doing the following:
`vehicle_count[0] += 1`

Comment: When I ran `vehicle_count[0] += 1` on my machine it adjusted both values, yes.

Comment: +1 great that is basically what I trying to ask, I didn't want to have type `vehicle_types[vehicle_type]` every time.

Comment: @JoshMartin No problem! If this solved your problem you should click the check mark by my post to accept it as the answer. This will signal to all other users that the problem has been solved :) When you get 15 rep you can upvote helpful answers too!